# What is a endomorphism of vector bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition

Quick question: When we say $f:E\to E$ is an **endomorphism** of the vector bundle $\pi:E\to M$, do we require that $f$ maps each fiber $E_p$ to itself, or it could be to another fiber $E_q$?

I couldn't find the answer online. Any reference?

Comment: One can certainly talk about vector bundle maps $f\colon E\to F$ covering $g\colon M\to N$ (where $E\to M$ and $F\to N$ are vector bundles). And one can take $N=M$ and maps $g$ other than the identity. So it really is a matter of convention/definition, but I would agree that *most* often one takes $g$ to be the identity when $M=N$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $f$ must map $E_p$ to itself. Here is how [Clifford Taubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_Taubes) defines it in his recent book [*Differential Geometry: Bundles, Connections, Metrics and Curvature*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199605874):

> Let $\pi: E\to M$ and $\pi': E'\to M$ denote a pair of vector bundles. A homomorphism
>   $\mathfrak{h}: E \to E'$ is a smooth map with the property that if $p \in M$ is any given point, then $\mathfrak{h}$ restricts to $E|_p$ as a linear map to $E'|_p$. An *endomorphism* of a given bundle $E$ is a homomorphism from $E$ to itself.